# How to solve a problem only on playstore?

Tags: java, android

I have a small problem that is difficult to debug.

Here is my case:

```
- My application uses encryption.

- When connecting via the login (locally), everything works fine (iOS and Android).

- For iOS, the application is available on the store and works fine too.

- For Android, when I test the beta version (via playstore) of my application with the same login, my application crashes.
```

The problem is that everything works fine locally for iOS and Android, but as soon as the Android application is on the play store, doing the same tests (same database, same url, same login/password), the application crashes, and I don't know why.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty key
at javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.<init>(SecretKeySpec.java:145)
at pb.a.f(Unknown Source:206)
at eb.g0.a(Unknown Source:295)
at jb.b$b.a(Unknown Source:12)
at oe.h.run(Unknown Source:27)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

I don't understand why it crashes **only** when the application is on the store and not when I test it locally.

I have logged where there is a difference in results..

**When I test my application locally :**

```
Log - derivation password : %s  D  myPassword.
Log - derivation user_id  : %s  D  789594a24e158304
Log - derivation resultat : %s  D  gw9yK5HAw7n9RjY0e4adWlpM5wUnA0GdM/L5kcD3EHs=
```

**When I test my application from play store :**

```
Log - Erreur derivation : %s    D  PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 SecretKeyFactory not available
Log - derivation password : %s  D  myPassword.
Log - derivation user_id : %s   D  789594a24e158304
Log - derivation resultat : %s  D
```

Via **playstore**, there is an error "**PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 SecretKeyFactory not available**" and resultat is empty.

My function :

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static String derivation(String password, String user_id) {

        String salt = "blablabla"+user_id;
        byte[] TabMotSaltBytes = salt.getBytes();  // stock salt in bytes

        int iterationCount = 1000;
        int KeyLength = 256; 

        String derivation = "";

        try {
            SecretKeyFactory pbkdf2 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
            PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), TabMotSaltBytes, iterationCount, KeyLength);
            byte[] secret = pbkdf2.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
            derivation = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Erreur derivation : %s", e.getMessage());
        }

        Log.d("derivation password : %s",password);
        Log.d("derivation user_id : %s",user_id);
        Log.d("derivation resultat : %s", derivation);
        return derivation;
    }
```

In my build.gradle :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
```

My question is : **Why is it that when I download the app from the playstore, it can't calculate the derivation key?**

It's the same phone, the same login, the same password, the same url, the same database..

Thx for your help :)

Comment: Are you aware that `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 ` requires an Android phone running Android 8+? Do you use Proguard obfuscated APK file for local testing?

Comment: I didn't know, but my test phone is running Android 10. I don't think I use ProGuard to obfuscate the APK locally, why ? (I'll find out how to do it..) 
If I send an apk not obfuscated by ProGuard, Google will do it for me and maybe that's why I don't have any problems locally but I do with the store version ?

Comment: Look at the stack trace of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty key`. `pb.a.f` is an obfuscated class name. Assuming this class is your code, then Proguard is active. If not it could be an already obfuscated library you use, but based on what you have posted this is not possible to tell.

Comment: I just checked my build.gradle and I see that there is ProGuard, I updated my first post with my build.gradle. 
Let's assume Proguard is active... why does the local version work fine and not the one on the store? what can be done to get the store version to work? (sorry, I'm new to this project and I'm trying to understand, thx for your help). 
Should I disable ProGuard to get more information about `pb.a.f` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the compatibility mode in `build.gradle`

Replace :

```
compileOptions{
     targetCompatibility = "11"
     sourceCompatibility = "11"
}
```

by

```
compileOptions{
     targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```